# Apply Arabic Language for layout Tablet Android

Tags: android, layout, arabic, tablet

I currently apply Arabic language and UI for my app.

I have layout-ar use for Arabic UI only in mobile and layout-sw600dp for tablet UI.
Now, when running to tablet, and choose the Arabic language, my app use layout XML in layout-ar to display instead of layout-sw600dp.
What I need is display layout XML in layout-sw600dp when running in tablet even if user choose the Arabic language.

Anyone have a solution, please help me.

Thank a lot.

Comment: Please take a look [at the Android official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources) on resources and how Android [finds the best-matching resource](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources#BestMatch).

Comment: I have to ask: why do you have an Arabic-specific layout?  It's possible you have a use-case I'm not thinking of, but are you sure you don't want an RTL-specific layout instead?  (this won't solve your problem, of course, but it might help with other things...)

Answer (score 0):

try combining classificators, e.g. create `layout-sw600dp-ar` folder